# How to prove that this space cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Take two Moebius bands glued together as in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npUHm.jpg). Now attach a $2$-cell along one of the boundary components of this space (indicated in green in the picture). Call the resulting space $X$. My gut feeling is that $X$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The question is: is this actually true, and if so, how do I prove this?

I thought of approaching this problem via Alexander Duality (which basically tells you that the homology groups $H_i$ of a compact and locally contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are trivial for $i \geq n$ and torsionfree for $i=n-1$ and $n-2$), but $H_i(X)$ are -- I think -- trivial for $i \geq 2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i=0$, $1$.

I also tried embedding a complete graph on six vertices into $X$ minus the $2$-cell and then arguing as in Maehara's paper "Why is $P^2$ not embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$?" (see also Gjergji Zaimi's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18987/why-cant-the-klein-bottle-embed-in-mathbbr3)), but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: I think you might be using a mountain to crush a mite. Try using classification theorem for surfaces with boundary. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Classification_of_closed_surfaces